Difference between tensorflow Dropout layer vs MultiHeadAttention argument dropout
I'm using tensorflow 2.10.1 to implement a transformer encoder. A lot of online tutorials introduce an explicit Dropout layer (e.g. here) after MHA, but I notice that the MultiHeadAttention layer as documented takes a dropout argument as well.
I understand that a tf.keras.models.Model class can take a training argument on call, which is passed to downstream layers to implicitly switch on/off any dropout layers (presumably including layers with a dropout argument), so is there any reason why I would add an explicit Dropout layer instead of passing a dropout argument to the MultiHeadAttention layer?
And in either case, does tensorflow automatically protect certain embeddings such as start/end of sequence tokens from dropout, as removing these (e.g. in a random dropout) can detrimentally affect the transformer behaviour?
